# Execute client command in safe interpreter

Tags: tcl, comm

I'm trying to write a program that user can read database on server through comm::comm command from client side. Now I want to prevent certain commands from client side such as "file delete", so I created a safe interpreter on server and want to make some settings on server to put all commands from client side to the safe interpreter. Does anybody know if there is any mechanism to achieve that? Any helpful answer will be appreciated!

Comment: did you try anything so far ?

Comment: I tried to rewrite comm command on client side to execute functions in safe interpreter on server, but this restriction should be on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for the `comm` package, especially the part about hooks for the `eval` event.

https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/comm/comm.html#subsection9

For example like this:

```
% interp create foo
% ::comm::comm hook eval {return [lb]foo eval $buffer[rb]}
% ::comm::comm send [lb]::comm::comm self[rb] set myvar 123
123
% set myvar
can't read "myvar": no such variable
% foo eval set myvar
123
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I want!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer, if you are happy with it.